# Elasticsearch 2.3 Delete all documents in a type by query using PHP LIbrary

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I want to be able to delete documents by query using the elasticsearch php library. I actually ideally want to delete all documents in my type.
I can achieve this using a normal curl XDELETE request in sense, however I cant get it to work using elastic search's PHP library.

Yes I have installed the `delete-by-query` plugin hence why raw request works.

my current code:

```
$params = [
    'index' => 'sanctions_lists',
    'type' => $listName,
    'body' => [
        'query' => [
            'match_all' => []
        ]
    ]
];
return $this->delete($params);
```

results in

> InvalidArgumentException in Client.php line 1440:
>   id cannot be null.

From my error message (ID cannot be null) it appears delete by query could be a limitation of the php library Only allowing deletes by id.

Would be a bit annoying if I have to execute raw HTTP request for this function inside my app when the php library has been really good for my other queries in the app.

**Question Summary**

Is there a workaround to delete by query using the elasticsearch php library without touching library code?

Goes without saying but thanks to anyone who takes any time to view and help with my question. Cheers.

**Edit**

Incase it helps im using:

elasticsearch php library version `v2.1.5`

Comment: What does the direct (raw) HTTP request look like when it works? (Knowing this will help in figuring out if there is a direct equivalent for submitting such a request via the library or if you would need to write additional code to get similar affect).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use the [`deleteByQuery()` function](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php/blob/2904d7a5df6884cbc3aae6192e49f883776e3fac/docs/build/Elasticsearch/Client.asciidoc#Elasticsearch_ClientdeleteByQuery_deleteByQuery), like this:

```
$params = [
    'index' => 'sanctions_lists',
    'type' => $listName,
    'body' => [
        'query' => [
            'match_all' => []
        ]
    ]
];
return $this->deleteByQuery($params);
```

If you want to have a look the source code is available [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php/blob/master/src/Elasticsearch/Client.php#L255-L286)

Comment: Nice. Any chance you are a contributor to the project that can poke the right people to get this added to the main docs for the library at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/2.0/ ? Or is there somewhere definitive that outlines which endpoints/methods are exposed in the library (so as to avoid trial-and-error of checking if a defined endpoint in ES will work when called as library method)?

Comment: Another SO contributor named [@AndreiStefan](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3498062/andrei-stefan) should know who to poke for this. There was [an opened issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php/issues/168) about exactly this problem, but it was closed 1 year ago.

Comment: Fantastic. Spent almost an hour trying to find this somewhere else. Works a charm

Comment: Yeah great tip on your part to check the source code. Ill be sure to do that next time. Thanks again

Comment: `deleteByQuery` is marked as deprecated, don't know if it is safe to use it?

Comment: @MārtiņšBriedis it's safe to use, since it re-appeared in version 2.4

Answer (score 15):

```
$params = [
    "index" => "my_index",
    "type" => "my_type",
    "body" => [
        "query" => [
            "match_all" => (object)[]
        ]
    ]
];

$client->deleteByQuery($params);
```

According to [@Val 's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37382980/elasticsearch-2-3-delete-all-documents-in-a-type-by-query-using-php-library#answer-37383094) answer, U may experience error, so note "match_all" => (object)[] retyping. I found that [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php/issues/495)