# ElasticSearch Delete by query not working in PHP

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I am using Elastic search 5.x and the following code is working fine:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test_index/test_info/_delete_by_query" -d'
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
        "category_id": "21"
    }
  }
}'
```

But when I am trying the same in my php code, its not working:

```
$client->deleteByQuery([
'index' => 'test_index',
'type'  => 'test_info',

    'query' => [
        'match' => [
                ['category_id' => 21]

        ]       
    ]
```

]);

Comment: Which version of the `elasticsearch-php` library are you using?

Comment: @Val I am using elasticsearch-php version 2.0

Comment: There you go, you need to use version 5 and you'll be good.

Comment: @Val ... thank you ... how can I use this in version 2.0?

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37382980/elasticsearch-2-3-delete-all-documents-in-a-type-by-query-using-php-library/37383094#37383094 you need version 2.4 at least

Answer (score 6):

You need to provide your `query` array inside `body` array of your parameters:

```
$client->deleteByQuery([
    'index' => 'test_index',
    'type' => 'test_info',
    'body' => [
        'query' => [
            'match' => [
                ['category_id' => 21]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]);
```

Comment: Without type is possible too (php 7.2 - ES 7.3)  ['index' => 'test_index','body' => ['query' => ['match' => ['keyword' => '123456']]],];

Answer (score 2):

this an old question, previous comments don't work anymore in 2020 :

```
$client->deleteByQuery([
    'index' => 'test_index',
   (there were a type here)  'type' => 'test_info',
    'body' => [
        'query' => [
            'match' => [
                (there were an array here) ['category_id' => 21]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]);
```

So the final code is :

```
$client->deleteByQuery([
    'index' => 'test_index',
    'body' => [
        'query' => [
            'match' => [
               'category_id' => 21
            ]
        ]
    ]
```